# Using .no-js class for detection of js

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I have always used the method of having a class of .no-js on the `<html>` tag, then using modernizr that strips the tag and replaces it with js if JavaScript is enabled in the user's browser.

Basically, I have built a CSS3 mobile and desktop navigation. I have styles to change its behaviour if there are CSS transitions etc (checked with modernizr) as well as if there is js or no-js.

The problem is, I get a flash of the no-js version before JavaScript has had time to load and change the class to js. (because the default class is no-js)

What I can't get my head around is how to find a fix for this. If I place js specific code as the main classes, then specify another with the prefix .no-js it flashes the no-js even if js is enabled. If I switch it over, it does the same...

Maybe I am being stupid, but any pointers would be great.

Comment: Are you delaying the execution of the script until the page has finished loading? If so, don't - you want it to execute before the page finishes rendering.

Comment: No, the script is made almost entirely of CSS. There is only one tiny line of jQuery.

Comment: One line is still technically a script. What does that one line look like and where is it located in your page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paul Irish has an [excellent blog post](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) on dealing with this problem.  Here's the solution from that post:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class='no-js'>
    <head>
        <script>(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement)</script>
        ...
```

The key is to make sure you've updated the classnames prior to the browser having a chance to render anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a short script at the very top of the `<head>`:

```
<script>
  document.documentElement.className =
    document.documentElement.className.replace('no-js', 'js');
</script>
```

Also don't forget about the `<noscript>` tag, which is ignored when JavaScript is enabled.